# Programming google app script to trigger at a specific time by displaying spreadsheet in email body

Tags: triggers, google-apps-script, builder, clock

I'm sending a spreadsheet in the body of an email everyday. I completed the email portion, but now im trying to program the trigger to set off at 1:15pm everyday. I'm not sure how to implement the code to trigger with the email?

```
'function nearMinute(minute) {
     var sendRead = ScriptApp.newTrigger("sendRead1pm")
          .timeBased()
          .atHour(13)
          .everyDays(1) // Frequency is required if you are using atHour() or atMinute()    
          .create();

     var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
     var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Totals");

     var subjecttable = UrlFetchApp.fetch("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/pub?
     key=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX=true&gid=1&output=html");
     var htmltable = subjecttable.getContentText();

     var fromName =  "DoNotReply - email";
     var rowData = ss.getRange("B16").getValues()[0];
     var emailAddress = "emailaddress@gmail.com";       // First column
     var message = {htmlBody: htmltable, name: fromName};       // Second column
     var subject = "TEST $" + rowData;

     MailApp.sendEmail(emailAddress, subject, "", message);

 }`
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to code your trigger. Make your function to do the email part and set up the trigger manually. In your script, go to `Resources --> Current Project's Triggers` and then add a trigger. This is the easiest.

Comment: Thanks for a quick response Srik! Is there a way to set up a specific time everyday?

Comment: No. You can only set it up to run at the hour. If you want to run it at a specific time, set up the trigger more frequently (say 5 minutes) and in your function, check if the current time is what you want 13:15 in this case.